# During boot: An error has occured while mounting(13.04)

Tags: boot, mount, automount

So I get this message during boot saying that it failed to mount the /home/chris/Videos/Anime drive.  It's the same kind of drive as my /home and /home/backup drives, formatted the same, etc... but it's the only one with the problem.

When Ubuntu loads, I can open the drive and it's then automounted at this point right where I want it. So I am unsure why it would fail during boot...

Here's my fstab:

```
UUID=1997e153-487e-497c-b061-37fc00ea70a2 /                            ext4    noatime,discard,errors=remount-ro      0       1
UUID=ec8090e1-8e44-44f9-b186-acb2259bdf58 /home                        ext4    defaults,noatime                       0       2
UUID=4870214c-28d8-4268-b783-e78be9df2423 /home/backup                 ext4    defaults,noatime                       0       2
UUID=e868db4b-bfd1-40d3-8e1c-0c3cd9e344ce /home/chris/Videos/Anime     ext4    defaults,noatime                       0       2
```

So far I have tried to mount it elsewhere and it seems I am unable to mount inside my "chris" folder, though like my backup drive I can mount it to my /home drive.  Am I not allowed to mount in that area?  If so, why would I only not be allowed during boot?  As mentioned if I open the drive it will auto mount to the directory I want.  This is only a minor inconvenience as I only have to deal with it once after I boot up and not worry about it again until I boot up again, but I'd still like to find out why.

Could it be a permissions issue?  Though wouldn't the fstab work as root?

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo blkid
```

to see if the UUID has changed. If it has, change your fstab accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, unfortunately it hasn't changed.